# Removing button from form dynamically on user input

Tags: c#, forms, button

I have a problem. I'm making a web browser in a C# Windows Form, and I've added bookmarks. My problem? Removing them. I can't seem to get good code that will remove the bookmarks! Here's my code:

```
private void button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int removeBookmarkI = 0;
        string removeBookmarkName = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction.InputBox("Which bookmark would you like to delete?", "Delete Bookmark", "Google");

        for (int i = 0; i < bookmark_names.Length; i++)
        {
            if (bookmark_names[i] == removeBookmarkName)
            {
                removeBookmarkI = i;
                string[] holdBookmark_names_temp = new string[bookmark_names.Length];
                string[] holdBookmark_url_temp = new string[bookmark_names.Length];
                for (int j = i; j < bookmark_names.Length - 1; j++)
                {
                    bookmark_names[j] = bookmark_names[j + 1];
                    bookmark_url[j] = bookmark_url[j + 1];
                }
                int skipNum = 0;
                for (int j = 0; j < bookmark_names.Length - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (bookmark_names[j] == removeBookmarkName)
                    {
                        skipNum = 1;
                    }
                    holdBookmark_names_temp[j] = bookmark_names[j + skipNum];
                    holdBookmark_url_temp[j] = bookmark_url[j + skipNum];
                }
                bookmark_names = new string[bookmark_names.Length - 1];
                bookmark_url = new string[bookmark_url.Length - 1];
                for (int j = 0; j < bookmark_names.Length; j++)
                {
                    bookmark_names[j] = holdBookmark_names_temp[j];
                    bookmark_url[j] = holdBookmark_url_temp[j];
                }
                this.Controls.Remove(buttonsAdded[removeBookmarkI]);
                buttonsAdded.Remove(buttonsAdded[bookmark_names.Length - 1]);
                this.Controls.Remove(buttonsAdded[bookmark_names.Length - 1]);

                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\\Users\\Public\\IAmAPerson_Web_Explorer\\bookmarks\\bookmark_names.txt", bookmark_names);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllLines("C:\\Users\\Public\\IAmAPerson_Web_Explorer\\bookmarks\\bookmarks.txt", bookmark_url);
                bookmark_names = new string[bookmark_names.Length - 1];
                bookmark_url = new string[bookmark_url.Length - 1];
                bookmark_names = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\IAmAPerson_Web_Explorer\bookmarks\bookmark_names.txt");
                bookmark_url = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\IAmAPerson_Web_Explorer\bookmarks\bookmarks.txt");
                bookmarkButtonSpacing -= 100;
                break;
            }
            if (i == bookmark_names.Length - 1)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("You do not have a bookmark named " + removeBookmarkName + "!");
            }
        }
    }
```

It *should* prompt for what bookmark you want to delete, remove it, shift all other bookmarks over, and remove it from the web explorer directory files. What's going on? How can I fix this? I'm using a list for my buttons called `buttonsAdded`. Also, I am aware that this code is probably the worst looking code in C# EVER, but I'm new, and I have yet to learn the best ways to code.

Comment: Just read your last sentence. I suggest you have a look at the different data structures available to you in `C#`. Arrays aren't what you want to work with. If you are going to be adding/removing elements from your array, then you want to use either a `List` or a `Dictionary` type structure. `Dictionary` seems the best suited here. You could eliminate most of that code.

Comment: You might want to look at ArrayList or Dictionary.

Comment: Thanks! ArrayLists seem to do very well with what I'm doing.